# Simplemodal not working correctly in ie8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, simplemodal

I've grabbed the exaple code for simplemodal straight off the simplemodal site. While the examples on that website work fine on ie8 from that website, after I copied and pasted everything into my own page (and copied over the relevant js files) the modal window opens at the bottom of the html page, not centred over the top of it. This only happens in ie8 - it works fine on Safari in both iOS6 and OSX. Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

Most probably IE8 is opened in quirks/compatibility mode in your case. Use [IE Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to manually control rendering mode. It is also possible [to force IE to render in standard mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374099/how-do-i-force-internet-explorer-to-render-in-standards-mode-and-not-in-quirks).