# Chained CSS classes for one html element not working in old IE versions

Tags: css, internet-explorer, quirks-mode

I ran into a problem that is not supposed to happen (which is why I'm puzzled): on **[THIS](http://www.petrebogdan.com/gegi/garfice.php)** page, the first item of the left side navigation menu has 2 chained classes attached - one for specific formatting as the **first item** and the other to show the **active state**.  Everything is fine in standard compliant browsers, but the *active state is missing in old IE versions*, including IE8.

That is especially annoying since IE8 is supposed to support multiple/chained CSS classes (as mentioned in *[this fine article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/14/css-differences-in-internet-explorer-6-7-and-8/)*.)

Can anyone give me a hand with this please? Thank you!

Comment: I can't see anythting that wouldn't work in IE7. I tested it in IE9 emulating IE8 and IE7, and it works fine. If it's not working in a real IE7, then it's most likely not because of the chained classes, but something else in the page. There is a Javascript error when loading the page, which might have something to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that when in IE, the document mode is "standardds" and not "quirks"

Comment: +1. You've tagged the question "quirks-mode". If your page really is using quirks mode, then that's the problem. Quirks mode will break pretty much any page design.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374099/how-do-i-force-internet-explorer-to-render-in-standards-mode-and-not-in-quirks

Answer (score 0):

Ok maybe it's not the solution, but at least try to add `!important;` to your active links.