# IE & Twitter Bootstrap (navbar + form elements) -- natural enemies?

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

So this one is bugging me out

I have a new layout using twitter bootstrap that is supposed to look like

[image: proper layout in chrome]

but in IE 7/8/9/10 looks like
[image: layout in IE]

the top navbar is fixed position, I've tried adding both padding & margin to the top  tag neither of which is recognized - I'm using bootstrap 2.3.1 though had the same issues with previous versions

any ideas besides chromeframe?

the site can be viewed at http://myterracefarmer.mitescreations.com

(just realized that I uploaded a screenshot of the homepage from chrome & the blog from IE though the issue stands for both pages)
screenshot of blog in chrome:: http://bit.ly/110O8gU

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5374099/1407478

Answer (score -1):

Took a fresh look over the debug tool in IE to track this one down

I am using sass for this project and had debug info turned on to speed up development through firefox -- this is a NO NO in IE

once I disabled the sass debug info it started displaying properly