# IE compatibility mode check

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

I have an asp .net website that renders fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE9 I need to use compatibility mode. I understand that I can force IE into compatibility mode, but I would much rather update the site so that compatibility mode is not necessary. How do determine what is forcing me to need compatibility mode? I suspect it is in my CSS.

Comment: CSS or JS are most likely. You can remove individual components until it works in IE

Comment: Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374099/how-do-i-force-internet-explorer-to-render-in-standards-mode-and-not-in-quirks). You'd need to use both `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>`.

Comment: The Doctype and meta tag works from Visual Studio but no IIS. Alos, this just forces compatability mode. I would really like to fix the underlying issue.

Comment: OK, I cleaned up the CSS file. Not exactly sure of the culprit, but I removed all text shadows, rounded corners and gradients, and I cleaned up the spaces/tabs. That seemed to do the trick.