# CSS - Different result on IE, please save me

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I am working on a OSCommerce site, and i can't figure out why is this happening.

You can check the website at the url: http://tendance24.com

The layout is completly different on IE and i'm wondering why cause all the should work for IE.

I am wondering if it couldn t be javascript.

Please let me know if you want me to upload all the css file somewhere, or anything else.

Thank you

Comment: because IE is a devil in web-world....please show us some html/css here!! :)

Comment: You shouldn't put a link to a live site here, as it will soon a later make the question and its answers obsolete. instead, please narrow down your problem to the part causing trouble, and create a jsFiddle with that. Also, mentioning which versions of IE on which OS might help...

Comment: in future try using browserstack to check results in different browsers, layout, except moved Languages dropdown menu looks mostly the same in IE9 and FF26.

Comment: Same here, no problem on Windows IE11, IE10, IE9. What version of IE you're looking at ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're seeing it using Internet Explorer's Quirks Mode.

The website will only render correctly using Internet Explorer in Standards Mode.

If you press F12 when the Browser is in view and you'll be able to change this from Quirks to Standards mode.

[This post will help solve the issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12421439/978264)