# Mouse hover on button not working in ie8?

Tags: html, css

I am working on asp.net mvc4 .when i mouse hover the button, colour is not changing.its always showing default blue focus on button.can anyone tell how to fix the issue.am using ie8.

```
    view :
      <input type="button" class="dynamicButton" value="button" id="btnSearch"/>
    css:
        .dynamicButton
           {
            height: 25px;
            width:auto;
             min-width: 11%;
            }
          .dynamicButton:hover
               {
                background-color:#4F2D7F;
                color:white;
                  }
```

I added

```
  <!doctype html>
```

into my code,but my page layout is changing after i added it.

Answer (score 0):

IE (not certain which versions), when in quirks mode, will not trigger hover state on anything but anchors. You *need* to specify a doctype (doesn't need to be <!doctype html>, others will do) to flip it to standards mode. If implementing a doctype messes with your layout, you will be better off in the long run fixing the layout issues.

Here's a related question discussing how to get IE into standards mode: [How do I force Internet Explorer to render in Standards Mode and NOT in Quirks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374099/how-do-i-force-internet-explorer-to-render-in-standards-mode-and-not-in-quirks)

Comment: if i add doctype my page layout changing

Comment: Then your layout has some issues that should be fixed. You need to make a decision: (1) Add the doctype and modify the layout so that it renders as you expect even with the doctype specified, or (2) forget about supporting the hover state on the input element in IE.