# Parsing ISO-8601 format date not working in IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I have a date (see dateValue variable) returned from the ajax response. Parsing that value works in chrome but not in IE 9.

Am I missing anything? Any help / suggestion is appreciated.

```js
var dateValue = "2015-08-12T16:31:51.68";

$('#result').text(Date.parse(dateValue));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="result"></label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISO-8601 date parsing was added in ES5, so not all browsers support it.

Check [this](https://github.com/csnover/js-iso8601) github project for an implementation that might work for you.

Or you could use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) for better cross browser capability.

```
var dateValue = "2015-08-12T16:31:51.68";
$('#result').text(moment(dateValue););
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added moment.js and used its methods. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

IE9 is in quirks mode, and you want it in standards mode.

To learn how to force standards mode, see this answer: [How do I force Internet Explorer to render in Standards Mode and NOT in Quirks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374099/how-do-i-force-internet-explorer-to-render-in-standards-mode-and-not-in-quirks)

When in quirks mode, [javascript only works if it was supported in IE6](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/03/24/ie9-s-document-modes-and-javascript.aspx).  `Date.parse` was not a JS feature in IE until [version 9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

To check if you are in quirks mode, run this JS:

```
alert('You are in ' + (document.compatMode==='CSS1Compat'?'Standards':'Quirks') + ' mode.')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have already forced IE to render in Standards Mode.