# font awesome not showing pin icon in IE 11

Tags: font-awesome

Viewing the following plunker in IE 11 shows now pin icons on the Name column. Viewing in FF or Chrome the pin icon is there. Any ideas why this might be?

http://plnkr.co/edit/RU4KnysM6s0aeYzI3KYJ?p=preview

```
.grid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.ui-grid-pinned-container .ui-grid-header-cell {
  position: relative;
}

.ui-grid-pinned-container .ui-grid-header-cell:after {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: '\f08d';
  font-size: .75em;
  right: 2em;
  top: 0.5em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-pinning></div>
</div>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Plunkr demo works fine for me in IE11. I imagine your issue is that IE is actually rendering your page in IE7 mode.

If you open your developer tools within IE (<kbd>F12</kbd>) you'll see a drop-down menu in the top right which says which version it's rendering on:

[image]

If this isn't displaying *11* by default, you can fix this by telling IE not to do this by adding this to your document's `<head>` (as described here: [How do I force Internet Explorer to render in Standards Mode and NOT in Quirks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374099/how-do-i-force-internet-explorer-to-render-in-standards-mode-and-not-in-quirks)):

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
```